# Oracle 10 G listener stat

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

i am getting that error always listner going down.then again i restart the database.
please give me solution.

```
NI connect error 12514, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=Eagle)(CID=(PROGRAM=EagleDataPushe
r11)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(USER=root))))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
        TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
        TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 20-FEB-2011 16:16:50
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12564
    TNS-12564: TNS:connection refused
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to turn on tracing for the listener to get more info. It's a little unclear exactly what you're experiencing. However, if you are able to connect for some time after a database restart (rather than a listener restart) but after a while you start getting this error, then this might suggest something is opening connections and not freeing them; eventually you'll reach the database's process or session limit. What kind of clients are connecting, and how? If you're able to connect locally as SYSDBA, look at `V$SESSION` and see if there are a lot of entries you aren't expecting.

Comment: select * from v$resource_limit where RESOURCE_NAME in ('sessions','processes','transactions');


RESOURCE_NAME                  CURRENT_UTILIZATION MAX_UTILIZATION INITIAL_AL
------------------------------ ------------------- --------------- ----------
LIMIT_VALU
----------
processes                                       28              31        150
       150


sessions                                        32              35        170
       170


transactions                                     0               7        187
 UNLIMITED

Comment: Hi

I fired the query and got that output.So, please tell me what we can do for this. if I can solve this issuue.

1)I ran select * from V$SESSION.

then lot of entries is coming but i am not able to undestand.

2)select * from v$resource_limit where RESOURCE_NAME in ('sessions','processes','transactions');

RESOURCE_NAME CURRENT_UTILIZATION MAX_UTILIZATION INITIAL_AL
LIMIT_VALU

processes 28 31 150 150

sessions 32 35 170 170

transactions 0 7 187 UNLIMITED

please give me any solution.

Comment: @user603152: 'lots of entries' doesn't add much; particularly as it still isn't clear whether it works for a while and then fails, and whether your queries were run when it was OK or broken. There will be quite a few internal processes all the time. Try repeating the queries with a gap to see if the current utilisation keeps growing over time, and gets close to the limit (150/170) before you start getting the error. If that is what's happening, you need to look at the content to see where the connections are coming from.